# Excel VBA ignores my IF statement to exit the sub

Tags: vba, excel

Excel ignores my programming statement that it should exit the sub if the item count is nothing

Given that it ignored the first IF statement, I tried to simply catch it with a second one, but it ignores that as well!

The code not only executes, but it just skips over all statements, and if I try to go through it line by line using F8, then it executes the full code.

I don't understand why it does this or what could cause it... Any help is appreciated.

```
 Private Sub SelectFolder()

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & " \"
    .Title = "Select Folder"
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        sPfad = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

If sPfad = "" Then Exit Sub

End Sub
```

UPDATE:
After getting this response which worked well when I tried it stepping through the code automatically, I realized that when I ran the whole procedure, my problem persisted.

Today I finally learned what is happening... the sub does in fact, as programmed, stop and end. THAT particular sub. However, since I'm calling it from a different sub in a procedure, the code then goes back to the calling sub and continues.

What I needed was simply to change `Exit Sub` to `End` since I needed the whole procedure to stop!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub SelectFolder()

   With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & " \"
       .Title = "Select Folder"
       If Not .Show Then Exit Sub
       sPfad = .SelectedItems(1)
   End With

End Sub
```

when user press *"Cancel"* - `.Show` returns `0` (`False`). But if user press *"OK"* - current folder in *FileDialog  window* is selected

Comment: +1 good point about the Show = [**`false`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa432435(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help! Works. I'll be selecting it as the answer as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach:

```
Private Sub SelectFolder()
Dim strPath As Variant
Dim sPfad As Variant
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & " \"
    .Title = "Select Folder"
End With

strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
    If strPath = False Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        sPfad = strPath
    End If
End Sub
```